# SQLite DB is readonly within kubernetes container

Tags: docker, sqlite, kubernetes

I have a SQLite deployed within a kubernetes cluster every time I try to add/modify its content I have the following error from kubectl logs :

`SqliteError { extended_code: 8, message: Some("attempt to write a readonly database") }`

I tried everything such as giving permission to my container within dockerfile or even from InitContainer but nothing works.

Do you have any idea ?
Thanks !

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  Especially in Kubernetes, you probably don't want to use SQLite: getting storage that can be shared between Pod replicas is tricky.  It's usually a better setup to run a standalone database like PostgreSQL in a separate StatefulSet, and have your application Deployment have no local state at all.